# What is the difference between reactant and reagent?

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between reactants and reagents? I've seen both used for very similar situations... The dictionary said that reagents are added to a reaction to identify another substance, but wouldn't that be an indicator?

Comment: There's no difference imo

Comment: SciFinder differentiates between them *somehow*

Comment: see also [reactant](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.R05163) and [reagent](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.R05190) in the IUPAC Compendium of Chemical Terminology (Gold Book)